# Toplevel in tkinter is creating another empty window at the side

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I am new in python.

I was trying to write a code with tkinter.
In click of a button it should open another window and close the previous window.
The code is closing the previous window correctly.

But the problem is it is also opening another empty window at the side on the screen.

Here's my code:

```
# The first part got no problem

from tkinter import *
import time


class Start:
    def __init__(self):

        self.first_screen = Tk()

        self.win_width = 500
        self.win_height = 500

        self.screen_width = self.first_screen.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screen_height = self.first_screen.winfo_screenheight()

        self.x_position = (self.screen_width / 2) - (self.win_width / 2)
        self.y_position = (self.screen_height / 2) - (self.win_height / 2)

        self.first_screen.title("Number game")
        self.first_screen.config(bg="#ffff00")
        self.first_screen.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (self.win_width, self.win_height, self.x_position, self.y_position))

        self.btn_play = Button(self.first_screen, text="Start", command=self.btn_play_click_action, width="10")
        self.btn_play.pack(side="top")
        self.btn_play.place(height=40, width=200, x=150, y=200)

        self.first_screen.mainloop()

        # This is where the problem happened
    def btn_play_click_action(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.first_screen.destroy()
        self.second_screen = Toplevel()
        self.second_screen.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (self.win_width, self.win_height, self.x_position, self.y_position))
        self.second_screen.title("Number game")
        self.second_screen.config(bg="#eeee00")
        self.label1 = Label(self.second_screen, width=50, bg="#000000")

        self.label1.pack(side="top")
        self.second_screen.mainloop()



Start()
```

Edit:

When I remove the " self.first_screen.destroy()" line, then the there is no problem.

Maybe it is because Toplevel needs a parent window. But I need to close the previous window. In this case what should I do?

Comment: Yes, a Toplevel needs a parent window. Instead of destroying the root window and then creating a new window, why don't you just reused the root window?

Comment: How to re-use the root window?

Comment: You can reuse the root window by destroying its children and then adding new children.

Answer (score 0):

You can not destroy the root window of the program which is self.first_screen = Tk().
Also, you dont need a mainloop for Toplevel window.
You can use .withdraw() method to hide root window instead of .destroy()

Here is you updated code -

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class Start:
    def __init__(self):

        self.first_screen = Tk()

        self.win_width = 500
        self.win_height = 500

        self.screen_width = self.first_screen.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screen_height = self.first_screen.winfo_screenheight()

        self.x_position = (self.screen_width / 2) - (self.win_width / 2)
        self.y_position = (self.screen_height / 2) - (self.win_height / 2)

        self.first_screen.title("Number game")
        self.first_screen.config(bg="#ffff00")
        self.first_screen.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (self.win_width, self.win_height, self.x_position, self.y_position))

        self.btn_play = Button(self.first_screen, text="Start", command=self.btn_play_click_action, width="10")
        self.btn_play.pack(side="top")
        self.btn_play.place(height=40, width=200, x=150, y=200)

        self.first_screen.mainloop()

        # This is where the problem happened
    def btn_play_click_action(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.first_screen.withdraw()
        self.second_screen = Toplevel()
        self.second_screen.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (self.win_width, self.win_height, self.x_position, self.y_position))
        self.second_screen.title("Number game")
        self.second_screen.config(bg="#eeee00")
        self.label1 = Label(self.second_screen, width=50, bg="#000000")

        self.label1.pack(side="top")
```

Answer (score -1):

There is unnecessary to make another window in `Toplevel()`. You can make it easier → Instead of `self.second_screen = Toplevel()` you can type `self.second_screen = Tk()`.